# Tile Layout plugin for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to implement a tiled layout for a website containing 9 tiles where one of the tiles is larger than the others. The basic `div layout` would look something like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="tiles1" class="inactive">
        Tile 1
    </div>
    <div id="tiles2" class="inactive">
        Tile 2
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles3" class="inactive">
        Tile 3
    </div>
    <div id="tiles4" class="active">
        Tile 4 (Active)     
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles4" class="inactive">
        Tile 4
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles5" class="inactive">
        Tile 5
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles6" class="inactive">
        Tile 6
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles7" class="inactive">
        Tile 7
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles8" class="inactive">
        Tile 8
    </div>
    <div id=id="tiles9" class="inactive">
        Tile 9
    </div>
</div>
```

The `div` that is marked with `class="active"` should be larger than the others. It might be possible that there are more tiles, but they would be hidden beneath a `load more` button.

A possible solution that I had in mind was to implement the tiles using nested grids in foundation and then add a listener for each `div` which flips the class.

The actual tiled layout would then be handled in CSS.

However, I was wondering if there exists a jquery plugin out there that already achieves what I am trying to do (along with the CSS) as that would reduce the workload for the designer.

Maybe someone has suggestions for plugins that I could try?

Thanks

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/v2/

Comment: Hey @mr.void, thanks for the response. We went ahead and implemented using HTML/CSS as we didn't want to add a library. Also, the layout that we had was a bit different than what I posted. We need 8 small tiles + 1 large tile arranged in a fixed grid with the contents of the large tile changing on clicking any of the small tiles. Masonry was not really the ideal solution for this.